# Why would God need to introduce Himself when revealing to forefathers?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, hashkafah-philosophy, theology, parashat-toldot

> וַיֵּרָא אֵלָיו ה' בַּלַּיְלָה הַהוּא וַיֹּאמֶר אָנֹכִי אֱלֹהֵי אַבְרָהָם אָבִיךָ ...׃ - That night the LORD appeared to him and said, “I am the God of your father Abraham. ...” [Genesis.26.24](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.26.24-25?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=Targum%20Jonathan%20on%20Genesis&lang2=en)

This is a very common way of God introducing Himself first when appearing to our forefathers and other righteous (see [Genesis.46.3](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.46.3?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&aliyot=0), [Exodus.3.6](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Exodus.3.6?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&aliyot=0)).

Why would God need to introduce Himself, would the forefather suspect that there's a different deity speaking to them?

Comment: it says G-d would make his voice sound like people the person he was talking to knew, e.g in the case of Moshe we see he made himself sound like Amram (Moshe's father) and with shmuel he sounded like Eli (shmuels mentor) in fact Shmuel thought that it was in fact Eli speaking to him so i presume its for this exact reason

Comment: Yes. How would he know who is speaking to him?

Comment: @larry909 Sorry, what are the options? To my best knowledge, we hold that the forefathers were pretty monotheistic.

Comment: @AlBerko there are dark forces out there as well. Also, when you call someone on the phone or otherwise and they can't see you, many times you'll say "hey joe, what's happening, this is Jack, how's it going?"